# ArcGIS for Server - Mosaic Data set layer definition query

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have a mosaic data set containing four raster images. I have published it on ArcGIS for server as a map service. I am applying Layer definition in export image interface at ArcGIS REST end. I have a text field on which I am applying the definition query. it works successfully in ArcMap but it doesn't work on Arcgis Rest Page of Export Map( showing Definition query is not working). I have tried with correct query and wrong query but it shows the image regardless of definition query.

I am using 
ArcGIS API for JavaScript  3.17
ArcGIS Server 10.2
ArcMap 10.4

**EDIT**

I can not share my arcgis server rest page. however for explaining my problem further i am using esri sample server.

1. This link shows a basic map export.(without any definition query). [Click here to see](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/export?bbox=7586498.2203842085%2C648193.5629549571%2C7628948.291202798%2C684915.0775039099&bboxSR=&layers=all&layerDefs=&size=&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&dynamicLayers=&gdbVersion=&mapScale=&rotation=&f=html)
2. The second link shows a map export with definition query applied. [Click here to see](http://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/911CallsHotspot/MapServer/export?bbox=7586498.2203842085%2C648193.5629549571%2C7628948.291202798%2C684915.0775039099&bboxSR=&layers=all&layerDefs=%7B%221%22%3A%22CALL_TYPE%20%3D%20%27SEESMOKE%27%22%7D&size=&imageSR=&format=png&transparent=false&dpi=&time=&layerTimeOptions=&dynamicLayers=&gdbVersion=&mapScale=&rotation=&f=html)

See the difference in images.

This is how i want definition query to work, however in my case its giving the same result. Hope now my question is clear.

Comment: Please **edit the question**  to specify *how* it "doesn't work". Since the client and server are two major (four minor) releases apart, have you considered that the desired functionality might have been introduced since 10.2.0?

Comment: Vince By definition query is not working i mean that data is shown regardless of definition query.

Comment: Does the server report an error message? "Not working" is an insufficent description. Please **edit the question** with details. Comments are only for requests for clarification.

Comment: There seems to be some code used but we are not seeing a code snippet to illustrate precisely what you have tested.

Comment: I am first testing it on the rest end of arcgis server.
i have added more details in my question.